Distinct sets with indistinguishable objects
You have 11 blocks, where nine of them are labeled 1 through 9 and the remaining two are indistinguishable labeled with 10. Compute the number of ways you can pick a set of three blocks such that at least one block is even.
What's confusing me is the "set of three" part here. The way I would solve it is:
$$(\text{At least one even}) \quad = \quad (\text{Total Ways of picking}) \quad - \quad (\text{None Even})$$
None even is simple to find out, where we can just choose 3 out of the 5 uneven ones. However, the total ways of picking is confusing me. The solution says its 11 Choose 3, however don't agree, as it counts (10,10,5) and (10,5,10) as distinct sets. Therefore, there should be fewer than 11 Choose 3 distinct sets. My approach would be to compute:
$$(\text{No tens and 3 non-tens}) \quad = \quad 9 \text{ Choose } 3 \quad = \quad 84$$
$$(\text{One ten and 2 non-tens}) \quad = \quad 9 \text{ Choose } 2 \quad = \quad 36$$
$$(\text{Two tens and 1 non-ten}) \quad = \quad 9 \text{ Choose } 1 \quad = \quad 9$$
thus, in total 129 distinct sets of three, which gives us
$$(\text{At least one even}) = 129 - 10 = 119$$
Where am I making a mistake here?

Let's denote the two boxes marked $10$ as $10_A$ and $10_B$. By doing this, we have made them distinguishable for the sake of discussion.
Actually, $\binom{11}{3}$ does not count $\{10_A, 5, 10_B\}$ and $\{10_A, 10_B, 5\}$ as separate sets, because they contain the exact same elements. The problem is that it considers, say, $\{1, 2, 10_A\}$ and $\{1, 2, 10_B\}$ as distinct sets, which they are not because the two boxes marked $10$ are indistinguishable.
That being said, your solution is correct. We can also see this by starting with the (incorrect) count of $\binom{11}{3}$ and removing the overcounted cases. In fact, you should check that the only overcounted cases are those that contain exactly one of the boxes marked $10$. There are $\binom{9}{2}$ of these, and each one was counted twice (one with $10_A$ and the other with $10_B$), so the answer is simply
$$\binom{11}{3} - \binom{9}{2} = 129$$
as you have obtained through casework.

To ask this quiz, the number of ways to select at least one even block is simply the total number of selections minus the number of selections where no even blocks are chosen. I don’t think there is any mistake in your answer.
